# Ant: "Duplicated project name in import" with imported build file

Tags: ant, build

I have several build files which all import the same base build file, like this:

**base.xml:**

```
<project name="base">
    <!-- does not define a 'build' target -->
</project>
```

**buildA.xml:**

```
<project name="buildA">
    <import file="base.xml" />
    <target name="build">
        <ant antfile="buildB.xml" target="build"
            inheritall="false" inheritrefs="false" />
    </target>
</project>
```

**buildB.xml:**

```
<project name="buildB">
    <import file="base.xml" />
    <target name="build">
        ...snip...
    </target>
</project>
```

(Module A depends on module B.)

Now, the above calling of B's `build` target from *buildA.xml* gives the following error:

`Duplicated project name in import. Project base defined first in buildA.xml and again in buildB.xml`

Since both *buildA.xml* and *buildB.xml* inherit the same *base.xml*, this seems unavoidable.

How could I get rid of this error?

Comment: Can't reproduce with ant 1.8.2. No errors with `ant -f buildA.xml build`.

Comment: Dang. It seems that I oversimplified the test case example. Sorry for that! In order to reproduce, you must duplicate the three files in two different directories and then have _buildA_ from dir1 call _buildB_ in dir2. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Didn't edit, but posted solution below. Thanks sudocode, I upvoted your answer and comment. :-)

Comment: Not sure about your solution, but I posted how I would do it in an updated answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on sudocode's answer, I solved the problem. Because the absolute path to *base.xml* is different in both cases, Ant does not recognize it as the same file. Even though `inheritAll` is set to `false`, the context of the calling task is preserved and this causes the name clash.

To solve this, one can omit the `name` attribute from *base.xml*. Since Ant 1.8, the [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) task has an attribute `as`, which can be used to reference base targets when the base project is nameless. If you don't override any targets, you can use [include](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/include.html) instead of `import`. I'm on 1.7, so that does not help me.

For previous versions of Ant, you can go through an [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) call to prevent proliferation of the Ant context entirely (then you get two running Ant instances). Better yet, find a way to import the exact same *base.xml* (with the same absolute path) in both files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ant 1.6? This [resolved Ant bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39920) looks like the same issue.

**EDIT**

I tried to reproduce the dir structure you refer to in your recent comment.

```
./base.xml
./buildA
./buildA/buildA.xml
./buildB
./buildB/buildB.xml
```

And amended the build files accordingly, e.g.

```
<project name="buildA">
<import file="../base.xml"/>
<target name="build">
  <ant antfile="../buildB/buildB.xml" target="build" inheritall="false" inheritrefs="false"/>
</target>
</project>
```

I still get no build error for the following with ant 1.8.2 or 1.7.1:

```
ant -f buildA/buildA.xml build
```

Comment: I am using Ant 1.7.1, and it's a slightly different issue. However, your answer got me thinking that I might be able to omit the project name on the _base.xml_. I'll try that tomorrow and post the results.

Comment: Yeah, all three files would have to be copied, including _base.xml_. I think I got it now (posted as answer). Thanks for helping me out on this!

Comment: You're welcome, but I don't understand what you mean about "all three files would have to be copied". Are you not using a single base.xml at a single location and referencing it in multiple files? If so, this works I have shown above.

Comment: Right, there are two copies of everything, including _base.xml_. This has to do with the build bootstrapping process. It gets the HEAD out of CVS, then determines the tag it should use, checks out the correct revision of the build process, and calls that. Most of the time, both copies are identical, but if a branch is being built, they differ. Obviously, the call to the correct version of the build scripts should not happen within Ant. Then we're ok.